# How to detect an HTTP redirect when importing or reading a URL?

Tags: internet

As an example, let's take the following URL:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Basidiomycete"
```

When you follow it, it redirects to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basidiomycota

So the question is: is there a way in Mathematica to follow `url` and detect the redirect? I would have thought that

```
response = URLRead[url]
```

would allow me to see the redirect in the generated `HTTPResponse` object, but if that is the case, I don't see how. (In this case, the wikipedia page body actually mentions that Basidiomycete redirects to Basidiomycota, but that's not what I mean).

Of course, the `HTTPResponse` does contain a status code, so that helps, but what about other types of redirect that still show as a 200 request? And how can I figure out what page I landed on? When using `URLRead[url]`, is there a way to find out that the content comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basidiomycota ?

Comment: For a workaround limited to wikipedia, you could use `Import[url]` and deduce the actual webpage from the article title.

Comment: True, but I'm not actually interested in the wikipedia-specific case. It's just a convenient example for which it's easy to find a redirection URL.

Comment: Then you might be able to achieve that with [WebUnit](https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/webunit) because it  allows you to control the browser, so you can access the current URL (I have not tried it for your example). But it is much slower than  `UrlRead`.

Comment: Well, that's at least something. It might come in handy, so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: URLRead[url]["StatusCode"] returns a 200 so there is no redirection, The the body data seems to be there completely. However, in a web browser the URL does change but I think that it does so instructed by some initialization JavaScript.

Comment: There are two types of redirections: on the server, or on the client side, see https://www.contentkingapp.com/academy/redirects/. Gustavo Delfino's comment can be confirmed on http://www.seoreviewtools.com/redirect-checker-tool/. So maybe you should specify a bit your question to specify which kind of redirection you would like to catch.

Comment: Ok, that's useful information, but I'd like to be able to catch any kind of redirect. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @anderstood and Sjoerd yes, and the server one can be hadnled by `FollowRedirects` option.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino If this is done with JavaScript, then why is `Import` affected even though it doesn't evaluate JavaScript?

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for pointing out the `FollowRedirects` option. It seems I had a wrong concept of what that did, exactly.

Comment: @C.E.  On my PC `Import[url, "Source"]` and `URLRead[url]["Body"]` produce the same result (except for a trailing \n and a different RequestId value)

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Yes, they produce the same result, but what is that result? They return the Basidiomycota page for me, not the Basidiomycete page. This contradicts the idea that the redirection is done with JavaScript. Maybe it is in the browser, but somehow the basidiomycota page is also returned to Mathematica, and that is not because of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no redirect. The URL `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Basidiomycete` returns the same page as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basidiomycota`.

When `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Basidiomycete` loads in a web browser, the shown URL is changed to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basidiomycota`. But if you disable JavaScript, this does not happen while the same page is shown.

Notice that the response include:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basidiomycota"/>
```

There is also inside a script this piece of JSON:

```
"wgInternalRedirectTargetUrl":"/wiki/Basidiomycota"
```

If you want to convince yourself that there is no redirect, follow the instructions at https://www.bearfruit.org/2008/04/17/telnet-for-testing-ssl-https-websites/

Comment: Ok, looks like I picked to wrong website to test this on :). Thanks a lot for helping figure this out!